# JNI how to increment pointer from GetDirectBufferAddress

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Lets say I have the following native JNI code where I get the address of the direct buffer

```
char* buffer_address = (char *)(*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,(jobject)r_directbuffer);
```

Is it legal to increment the pointer buffer_address? Like we do it in C

```
buffer_address+=4; //increments the pointer 4 bytes
```

And later I want to pass this incremented pointer to some other function, lets say memcpy

```
memcpy(buffer_address, src, 10); // 10 bytes to copy
```

So how to do those things, I don't want to copy the entire contents of the buffer_address to native C and then use it.

Comment: Can I use `GetByteArrayRegion` on `buffer_address` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your examples are OK. That's how pointer arithmetics works. Be careful, though: your self-discipline is the only protection to keep inside the bounds of the original direct buffer. E.g. make sure that `r_directbuffer` is at least 14 bytes long for the example above.

Don't get confused: manipulations on `buffer_address` do not change the **DirectByteBuffer** from which you got the pointer. Furthermore, JNI does not synchronize the life span of the pointer with the **jobject**.

---

No, you cannot use [GetByteArrayRegion()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp6212) on `buffer_address`. You cannot even use it on `r_directbuffer`, though it's *closer*. You can use it only on Java byte arrays, either **jbyteArray** or **jobject** of **byte[]** type.